# Get plain text from SunAwtCanvas

Tags: java, winapi, canvas, getmessage

Since it's impossible to capture text from a java canvas by using standard Windows API functions like `GetMessage()`, I wondered if there is any way to hook the `drawText()` method inside such a java canvas and to capture the text before it's actually have been drawn on the canvas. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? A solution written in java would also be accepted. Any suggestion would be nice, thank you.

Edit:
Is it possible to steal the foreign canvas handle and set it to my own canvas? So the foreign application wouldn't draw anymore to its canvas but to my spoofed one. By this way I could override the `drawText()` method easily in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java Instrumentation to inject code into drawString(), for example with Javassist.

You can combine code from [here](http://isisblogs.poly.edu/2011/12/25/java-dynamic-instrumentation-1/) to inject your code with `insertBefore` and [there](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/24/add-logging-at-class-load-time-with-instrumentation.html) to activate the transformation in the `premain` method.

Comment: I don't have any source code from the application i want to capture its canvas.

Comment: You do not need the source code. Instrumentation is a method to change the Byte Code at runtime.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how this would work with an example?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy enough to write your own subclass of `Graphics2D` and have the drawing done on that; your subclass could override `drawString()` to do whatever you'd like. I would probably write the implementation as a wrapper which forwarded all method calls to another instance specified as a constructor argument, as that way your subclass could be used to directly write to the screen. Be sure to implement `create()` to return a new instance of your subclass, of course.

Comment: Thank you. Did you consider that I want to capture the text from a foreign application, not of my own? Some links or sample codes would be very nice. Take a look at my edited question too, thanks.